# Finding Positive Odd Integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, optimization

$m$ is a positive odd integer.
$(m+4\times 41)(m^{2}+4^{2}\times 41^{2})$ is a perfect square.
Find the minimum value of $m$

Comment: A computer search shows that the first occurance is $m=205 = 5 \cdot 41$. So $m+4 \cdot 41 = 369 = 3^2 \cdot 41$ and $m^2+(4 \cdot 41)^2 = 68921 = 41^3$.